# By Jquery making divs, need them also to move up, like in a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById("aDiv").offsetTop);
 var e = document.getElementById("aDiv");
 var s = 1;
 setInterval(function(){
     var eLeftPos = e.offsetTop;
     // console.log(eLeftPos);
     e.style.top = (eLeftPos - s) + 'px';

 }, 200);
               // Animation

 (function makeDiv(){
     var divsize = 30;
     var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
     $newdiv = $('<div/>',{
      "class": "bubble theRestBubbles",
      "id": "bDiv"

     }).css({
         'width':divsize+'px',
         'height':divsize+'px',
         'background-color': color,
         'border-radius' : 50 + "%",
         // 'class' : 'bubble',
     });



     var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document.getElementById("mainBlock")).width())).toFixed();
       $newdiv.css({
         'position':'absolute',
         'left':posx+'px',
         'top':370+'px',
         'display':'none'
     }).appendTo( '#mainBlock' ).fadeIn(1000).delay(00, function(){
        // $(this).remove();
        makeDiv();
     });
      })();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bubble").click(function(){
        // $("input").append(" <b>Appended text</b>");
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var y = (parseInt(x, 10) || 0) + 1;
        x = y;
        console.log(x);
        $('#input').val(x);
       var currentPosition = this.offsetTop;
        console.log(currentPosition);
        this.style.top = "370px";
       });
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){

        $('#input').val("");
    });

});
```

```css
.bg{
 height: 400px;
 /*width: 400px;*/
 background-color: #FFF1F1;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 position: relative;
}

.bubble{
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #24E93E;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-xs-3 btnDiv">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">RESET</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">PLAY</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6  bg main-block" id="mainBlock">
    <div class="bubble testBubble" id="aDiv"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3 score-place">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi All.
Here I have a div, and by Math.Random a little dives are appearing. Now I need them to go up like the one I have at the beginning of the page.
Also When I click on the first and only the second div, there is a input, and the value +1. But the trick is that after first 2 divs, on clicking the rest ones, the value of input stays the same.
Will be glad if you will tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: This is not a "solve my homework" website. Try to create a solution first and then come if you run into trouble you can't solve yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all - you're question is very unclear - so I hope I understood you.

a. you want all the `div`s to bubble up - so why did you use `getElementById` ?
this will always return only one element + you do it before the interval so it's always the same one. try:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.bubble').each(function(){
       var e = this;
       var eLeftPos = e.offsetTop;
       e.style.top = (eLeftPos - s) + 'px';
    })
}, 200);
```

b. only clicks on the original div are counted - that is because you set the click only on load where there is only one div available. try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').on('click',".bubble",function(){ // this is the only line I changed
        // $("input").append(" <b>Appended text</b>");
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var y = (parseInt(x, 10) || 0) + 1;
        x = y;
        console.log(x);
        $('#input').val(x);
       var currentPosition = this.offsetTop;
        console.log(currentPosition);
        this.style.top = "370px";
       });
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){

        $('#input').val("");
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes it was the the solution I wanted, it solved the problem.